# I am running a javafx program and I am getting an IllegalStateException in a situation where I would expect usual Thread interference

Tags: multithreading, javafx

tl:dr at the bottom. I am taking a Java course on Udemy and our instructor is demonstrating a situation where background threads can interfere with each other and crash the program. In this case pushing either of the two buttons initiates a method that starts a background Thread, waits, then updates a label. He explains it something along the lines as the threads overwriting each other causing the program to crash with an IllegalStateException. What I don't understand is Threads overwriting each other is not uncommon and just makes the program behave in ways not intended and doesn't usually completely crash the program.
In this case the threads are both trying to change the label to the same String. 
Why is this throwing an IllegalStateException instead of just causing the usual interference? After all more than one thread trying to update an object doesn't necessarily crash the program.
tl:dr Why does more than one thread modifying a Label object throw an IllegalStateException in this case but in other multi-threaded programs you just get the usual thread interference? The method of interest is the onButtonClicked() method.

I have tried catching the IllegalStateException to see if I can call Thread.currentThread().getName() but the catch block(both of them actually) seem to get ignored.

public class Controller {

```
@FXML
private TextField nameField;
@FXML
private Button helloButton;
@FXML
private Button byeButton;
@FXML
private CheckBox ourCheckBox;
@FXML
private Label ourLabel;

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    helloButton.setDisable(true);
    byeButton.setDisable(true);
}
@FXML
public void onButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource().equals(helloButton)) {
        System.out.println("hello, " + nameField.getText());
    } else if (event.getSource().equals(byeButton)) {
        System.out.println("Bye, " + nameField.getText());
    }

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                ourLabel.setText("We did something");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Interuppted Exception " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                System.out.println("Illegal State Exception: " + e.getMessage() + " "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
    if (ourCheckBox.isSelected()) {
        nameField.clear();
        byeButton.setDisable(true);
        helloButton.setDisable(true);
    }
}

@FXML
public void handleKeyReleased() {
    String text = nameField.getText();
    boolean disableButtons = text.isEmpty() || text.trim().isEmpty();
    byeButton.setDisable(disableButtons);
    helloButton.setDisable(disableButtons);
}

@FXML
public void handleChange() {
    System.out.println("The checkbox is " +
            (ourCheckBox.isSelected() ? "checked" : "not checked"));
}
```

}

Comment: `ourLabel.setText("We did something");` in the `Runnable` is problematic. You can not update the GUI from a background thread. This code should be wrapped in `Platform.runLater`.

Comment: jewelsea's answer is a good one, but here would be an example what could go wrong that does not result in an exception being thrown in your own code: Remove a node from the child list of some parent. `parent.getChildren().remove(someNode);` if the `layoutChildren` method of `parent` contains logic like this: `for (int i = 0, size = getChildren().size(); i < size; i++) { Node child = getChildren().get(i); ... }` This can result in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` during the layout logic executed by JavaFX.

Comment: What's even worse is the fact that java is not required to "show" changes to all threads. The JavaFX application thread could have some of the state of a node update while others will never make their way to the application thread leaving it in a potentially unrecoverable state.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! All your answers were very helpful. This is my first question to this site despite my using it for a reference for the past year or so. I honestly wasn't sure I would get any replies. This is an awesome community!

Answer (score 4):

Updating active scene graph elements (such as label text) in your own threads has the potential to cause a [race condition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) (please read and understand the Software section of the link) in the internal state of the JavaFX system.  The results of which are unpredictable and a corruption or ”crash” of the JavaFX system cannot be ruled out.  Perhaps nothing bad will happen, but perhaps something bad will.

Some calls to JavaFX APIs will detect when potential race condition may occur (when they are being invoked by a thread which is not the JavaFX thread), and fail fast by throwing an IllegalStateException.  Other JavaFX APIs may not bother to check the calling thread and may not throw an IllegalStateException, thus allowing the potential race condition to occur.  Either way, the users calling code is wrong, it should not be trying to modify the active scene graph off of the JavaFX application thread.

JavaFX code which manipulates the active scene graph (elements or properties of elements currently being displayed in a rendered scene) is only ever expected to occur on a single thread (the JavaFX application thread).  In that way a race condition cannot occur.

If you want to feedback information from another thread to the UI, then you can either use the `Platform.runLater` API, which will execute a piece of code at some time in the future on the JavaFX thread, or make use of utilities in the `javafx.concurrent` package.

Comment: Wow! That explained things very well. My instructor does go on to say that the Platform.runLater API is a way to work around this issue but I wish he would have have explained the error better instead of glossing over it. Thanks again!